# DBAL - symfony2 bind a value for LIKE operator

Tags: symfony, dbal

I am trying to execute a sql query that involves a LIKE operator with DBAL

Basically my query is the following:

```
public function getSubsiteByHostname($host){

    $sql = "SELECT A.id, A.title, A.layout_id
    FROM sites AS A
    LEFT JOIN layouts B
    ON A.layout_id = B.id
    WHERE A.baseurl LIKE '%:host%'
    ";

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue("host", $host);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetch();
}



SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'hostname.dev'%
```

Obiviously I'm doing something wrong with the bindValue

Comment: Have you considered doing something like `$stmt->bindValue("host", '%'.$host.'%');` ?

Comment: I was just trying that and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is easier than I thought, like Adam suggested

```
$stmt->bindValue("host", '%'.$host.'%');
```

Comment: in php 7.1 it can shorten it to: `"%$host%"`