# PDO SELECT LIKE Is Not finding anything

Tags: php, pdo

Hey guys so am trying to find anything that has something like Angel in the title but for some reason its not returning anything example i got a movie title with

The Woman in Black 2: Angel of Death (2014)

But it keeps saying Nothing found any help would be awesome thanks!

```
<?php
require_once("../connection/config.php");
global $instance;

$search="Angel";
$query = $instance->prepare("select * from movies where title LIKE '%$search%'  LIMIT 0 , 10");
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

         if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
                echo "Search found :<br/>";
                echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>Movies</tr>";
            while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo $results['title'];
                echo "</tr>";
            }
                echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo 'Nothing found';
        }
?>
```

Comment: Replace `'%search%'` for `?`

Comment: That didn't work just tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can insert the variable in quotes when binding or it will be converted to a string. I believe you will need to add the wildcards beforehand.

```
$search="%Angel%";
$query = $instance->prepare("select * from movies where title LIKE ? LIMIT 0 , 10");
$query->bindValue(1, $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Sadly it didn't work :( still says nothing is found, Thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: Must be because your `count` isn't what you're expecting. Try this, `$count = $query->rowCount();` then echo it.

Comment: Got it to echo returned 0.

Comment: It may be returning 0 because it's false meaning that the query failed.

Comment: I just tried something to try the query i removed the search made it $search = "%%"; it returned the first movie that i added...

Comment: If you do `select * from movies where title LIKE '%Angel%' LIMIT 0 , 10` directly in mysql do you get a result?

Comment: Needed the quotes in the previous comment.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6t5gv7 << When i tried it directly,When i tried it with just %% http://prntscr.com/6t5fty

Comment: Try it directly in mysql (not PHP), with the quotes.

Comment: It says mysql returned an empty result.

Comment: So there is the problem, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay now this is really stupid of me am very sorry your answer works perfectly its just my brain that is really dumb i updated the phpmyadmin via the webhost not localhost x.x marking your answer thank you very much for your guy's help.

Comment: I see, don't worry about it. Sometimes it's the simple things that are the most difficult :)

Answer (score 1):

This should be -

```
$query = $instance->prepare("select * from movies where title LIKE :val  LIMIT 0 , 10");
$query->bindValue(':val', "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: This is wrong and won't work you should remove both `%` in the query.

Comment: For some reason its saying nothing found x.x

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299364/dbal-symfony2-bind-a-value-for-like-operator

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$query = $instance->prepare("select * from movies where title LIKE :search LIMIT 0, 10");
$query->bindParam(':search, '%'.$search.'%');
$query->execute();`

Comment: Any errors or just empty return? Plesse enable query logging SET global general_log = 1;
SET global log_output = 'table'; and check the generated SQL